# Изменение переменной в классе

Tags: java, android

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

 AddToLog("--запустилось периодическое событие...");
```

вот в этом месте нужно присвоить переменной `gcontext` из класса `ParseTask` значение context т.е. что-то типа:

```
ParseTask.gcontext=context
```

непосредственно перед исполнением `new ParseTask().execute();`

```
new ParseTask().execute();
SendMessage(context,"Hello","Перевед-перевед");
```

сам класс ParseTask

```
public class ParseTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String resultJson = "";
        Context gcontext;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

создайте конструктор

```
// переменная класса
private Context gcontext;

// конструктор класса
public ParseTask(Context context) {
    this.gcontext = context;
}
```

и при вызове сделайте

```
new ParseTask(context).execute();
```